# Is it possible to do this proof without a delta-epsilon argument?

Tags: real-analysis

I know how to do this with a $\delta-\epsilon$ argument($\epsilon/2$), but is it legal to do it this way?:

Let $(Y,||\cdot||)$ be a normed vector-space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Show that if the sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ in Y converge to **x** and **y**, respectively, then $\{x_n-y_n\}$ converges to **x-y**.

**solution:**

$$x-y=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n-\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n=\lim_{ n\rightarrow \infty}(x_n-y_n)$$

Is this sollution valid?

Comment: The solution is valid if a general theorem has been proved, say for linear combinations.

Comment: You could write the argument this way: from the triangle inequality, addition is continuous.  Given this fact, your argument is then fully rigorous.  But this is essentially the same argument as given below.

Answer (score 2):

No - you need to justify $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n - \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n -y_n)$.

Consider this proof:
Let $\epsilon >0$. Then, there exists $N$ such that $||x_n - x|| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, $||y_n - y|| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, since $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$.

Then, $|| (x-y) - (x_n - y_n) || = || (x - x_n) - (y - y_n) || \leq || x - x_n || + ||y - y_n|| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$ for $n \geq N$.

Thus, $x_n - y_n \to x-y$.